# Reformat datetime value with regex in a textfile

Tags: python, regex, datetime, reformatting

I want to change the time format in some text lines with using regex.
How can I use the old time values?
My code until now:

```
def file_replace_words(file_in, word_to_replace, replace_with):
    f = open(file_in, "r+")
    data = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in data:
        line = re.sub(word_to_replace, replace_with, line)
        f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

f.file_replace_words(path_putty_log, r"(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d) - \d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\d", 
                    "my time in format 31.12.1999 11:54:23")
```

I want to change the values from 29/09/16 - 16:38:09:808 to 29.09.16 16:38:09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add some more capturing groups into your regex, and use a replacement pattern with corresponding backreferences.

Use

```
r'(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) - (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d):\d{3}'
  |- 1-| |- 2-| |-3 -|   | ----- 4 ---- |
```

and replace with `r'\1.\2.\3 \4'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUQ5jN/1).

NOTE: If there are longer substrings that look like these datetime stamps, you might want to enclose the whole pattern with word boundaries `\b`: `r'\b(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) - (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d):\d{3}\b'`.